# How do I scale an SVG that has some complex path definitions?

Tags: svg, scale

I have an SVG whose code is like what follows:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="150px" height="150px" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" viewBox="0 0 150 155" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g id="g11" transform="matrix(1.25,0,0,-1.25,-100.0791,954.14501)">
        <g id="g3186" transform="translate(6.3490095,-13.703287)">
            <path d="..."></path>
            <path d="..."></path>
            <path d="..."></path>
            <path d="..."></path>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

The "original" dimensions of the SVG generate an image is that is 300px by 310px. I want to scale the image as a whole, let's say by 50%. I've tried a variety of ways to scale the image, but the best I've accomplished is to simply clip or "crop" the original image to a region that is 50% of the original dimensions.

Using preserveAspectRatio, setting the viewbox, trying to use transform="scale(0.5"), etc. have not worked. All I want to do is scale the original dimensions by 50%.

Answer (score 30):

`transform="scale(0.5)"` should definitely work. You're probably doing something else wrong.

Try wrapping `g11` in another `g` with `transform="scale(0.5)"` and remove the `preserveAspectRatio` and `viewBox`

Comment: But the problem with scale down with CSS transforms is that the object has still its original size (despite looking smaller), so the layout doesn't look good... at least that is my experience with it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how I'm doing it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <!-- this came from Open Clip Art http://openclipart.org/tags/svg 
         I just took the bits inside the g tag and gave them an id -->
    <svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >
        <defs>
            <g id="factory2">
                <g id="layer1" transform="translate(-190.12 -497.04)">
                    <path id="path3019" d="m260.18 638.49c-12.375-0.3028-33.202-0.51166-    46.283-0.46413l-23.783 0.0864 0.54057-2.5363c0.29731-1.3949 0.72336-10.785 0.94678-20.867 0.22343-10.082 0.61582-18.541 0.87198-18.797 0.6619-0.66189 5.5186 2.3677 12.539 7.8218l6.0422 4.6941 2.6179-4.6941c1.4398-2.5818 3.2323-5.8073 3.9833-7.1678 0.75098-1.3605 1.8059-2.6205 2.3442-2.7999 0.53833-0.17944 3.4031 1.6087 6.3662 3.9737 14.183 11.32 13.44 10.876 15.062 9.0051 0.81257-0.93784 2.5493-4.5177 3.8593-7.9552 1.3101-3.4375 2.6092-6.2494 2.887-6.2486 0.2778 0.00077 4.2211 3.6008 8.7629 8s8.6861 7.9986 9.2095 7.9986c1.661 0 5.5112-4.8335 7.5569-9.4868 1.0867-2.4718 2.2704-4.4985 2.6305-4.5037 0.36009-0.005 4.9112 4.2194 10.114 9.3881l9.4588 9.3976-0.36231 12.268c-0.19928 6.7473-0.57659 12.482-0.83847 12.744-0.71531 0.7153-9.6348 0.75231-34.526 0.14325zm-53.812-3.6334c-0.72187-0.28887-1.5844-0.25335-1.9167 0.0789-0.33229 0.33229 0.25834 0.56864 1.3125 0.52522 1.165-0.048 1.4019-0.28494 0.60417-0.60416zm52.618-13.034c0.27612-3.8066 0.0559-4.2797-2.2628-4.8616-1.4128-0.35458-4.5879-0.34189-7.0559 0.0282-4.4272 0.66389-4.4872 0.72466-4.4872 4.5421 0 4.3193 0.69024 4.6694 9 4.5649l4.5-0.0566 0.30588-4.2169zm-34.556 2.4532c-0.1375-0.40496-0.25-2.3113-0.25-4.2363v-3.5h-13v7.8954l5.25 0.37628c6.7165 0.48138 8.3091 0.37478 8-0.53546zm17.25-3.2363v-4l-6.75-0.29569-6.75-0.29569v3.879c0 2.1335 0.31903 4.1981 0.70896 4.588 0.38993 0.38992 3.4274 0.57742 6.75 0.41666l6.041-0.29229v-4zm32.5 0.5v-4h-12v8h12v-4zm16.267 0.75c0.27194-1.7875 0.29645-3.5875 0.0545-4-0.24197-0.4125-3.3384-0.75-6.8809-0.75h-6.441v8h12.773l0.49443-3.25zm-82.457-1.5-0.31037-3.75h-5.7837c-4.0517 0-6.0685-0.44918-6.7347-1.5-0.67184-1.0597-0.95549 0.0411-0.96631 3.75l-0.0153 5.25h14.121l-0.31036-3.75zm13.69-19.25c-0.33992-0.55-1.068-1-1.618-1s-0.72189 0.45-0.38197 1 1.068 1 1.618 1 0.72189-0.45 0.38197-1zm-13.665-0.75c-1.26-1.4949-1.4649-9.1853-1.405-52.75l0.0701-51 3.3219 0.15527c1.8271 0.0854 3.5772 0.4105 3.8891 0.72245 0.31195 0.31195 0.73146 10.142 0.93225 21.845 0.2008 11.703 0.79871 30.278 1.3287 41.278 1.2527 26.001 0.96626 31.906-1.8072 37.25-2.3841 4.5942-4.0201 5.2403-6.33 2.5zm27.665-1.9051c-1.1986-2.8686-1.388-5.8273-0.88023-13.75 0.35583-5.5522 0.69953-20.895 0.76378-34.095 0.12983-26.675 0.48916-28.507 4.9502-25.245 1.5369 1.1238 1.7803 4.6464 2.3358 33.807 0.55628 29.202 0.44258 33.086-1.1049 37.745-2.0404 6.1432-3.9393 6.6248-6.0646 1.5383z"/>
                </g>
            </g>
        </defs>
    </svg>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var svg = d3.select("svg") .append("g");

        var nodes = [{ name: "1", type: 'factory2' }];

        var node = svg.selectAll("node")
                .data(nodes)
                .enter()
                .append("g")
                .attr({
                    dx:50, dy:50, width:50, height:50,
                    // here's the magic
                    transform:"scale(0.5)"
                });

        node.append("use")
                .attr({
                    "xlink:href": "#factory2"
                });

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```